# Chrome is downloading both webm and mp4 HTML5 videos sources on page load

Tags: html, video, optimization, mp4, webm

I'm working on making page loads faster for my website. It seems as if Chrome is loading both of the HTML5 video files that are listed. As I understand, the browser is supposed to select the first video that works. In Chrome developer tools under the network tab, it shows that both videos are being downloaded on page load.

Is there any way to stop both loads from happening? Here is my code: (the data attributes are for skrollr.js)

```
<video id="video" preload="auto" autoplay muted class="landscape deskVid" loop poster="/img/eventsPoster.jpg"
                    data-anchor-target=".header"
                    data-top="display: block; opacity:1; transform:translateY(0px);"
                    data--60p-top="display: none; opacity:0; transform:translateY(0px);"
                >
                <source src="/img/eventsVideo.webm" type="video/webm">
                <source src="/img/eventsVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4"> </video>
```

Comment: Where's the opening `<video>` and why is there two closing `</video>` tags?

Comment: Hi there. I wanted to redact some of the code (names of pictures etc) before posting to stack overflow. While doing this, I accidentally posted some inaccurate code. (two </video> tags) 

I'll edit my post now to what I actually have.

Answer (score 0):

When I list a webm source followed by an mp4 source in a `<video>` tag, Chrome only accesses the webm source.  There is probably an issue with your webm source.  It may not be valid webm or your web server may not be reporting the correct Content-Type in the HTTP Response Headers (should be `video/webm`).